# In django is there a way to access the selected ForeignKey field value in a ModelForm to filter another ForeignKey in the form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

In django 4.1.3

Trying to filter a ForeignKey field query using another selected ForeignKey field value in a ModelForm to limit the filter depending on the selected exhibitors corresponding id.

```
from django import forms

from .models import Entry, Exhibitor, Pen

class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:     
        fields = ('exhibitor', 'pen', 'class_id',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                                                    # Can't figure out how to filter
                                                    # Using the selected exhibitor field value
        self.fields['pen'].queryset = Pen.objects.filter(current_owner_id=1) 
                                                    # where 1 should be the exhibitor_id
# using an int value for the current_owner_id works to filter the query 
# but don't know how to access selected field values, or would this work in a pre_save function?
```

`# tried`

`self.fields['pen'].queryset = Pen.objects.filter(current_owner_id=`**`self.fields['pen']`**`)`

> *TypeError at /admin/exhibitors/entry/add/ Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x2b630a6b2100>.*

Answer (score 0):

You have a ModelForm. It means, your form has always an instance of Entry.
in this case you can do:

1. Use instance attribute:

   class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):

   ```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...  # any staff
        exibitor = self.instance.exibitor
        ...  # any staff
   ```
2. Use `boundedfield.value` method:

   class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):

   ```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...  # any staff
        exibitor = self['exibitor'].value()
        ...  # any staff
   ```
3. You can get 'exibitor' before and send it in `form.__init__`:

   ```
    formentry = EntryForm(.... initial = { ..., 'exibitor': something })
   ```
4. The best way - to change Pen.Queryset in formfield_callback method in ModelForm Factory.
   More here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/models/#modelform-factory